# What happens when you force quit during a public game?

Tags: diablo-iii

I'm playing Diablo III with a hardcore character and I was wondering what would happen if I were to forcibly quit the game at any point. When I log back in will I appear in a town?

Comment: pretty sure (but not positive) your char still goes through the 10 seconds before disconnect so you'll still die.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your character remains in the game for the full duration of the normal log out process - if you're in town you instantly disconnect and if you're out of town then you will remain in the world for ten seconds.

When you log back in you will be in town, as per normal instances when you join a new game.